# Oracle PL/SQL block succeeds with hard coded value but not with variable

Tags: oracle, plsql

The following PL/SQL successfully executes as expected:

```
declare
    myCount number;
begin
    select count(*)
    into myCount
    from myTable
    where id = 1;
end;
```

However, the following does not and instead throws this error:

> ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

```
declare
    myCount number;
    myId number := 1;
begin
    select count(*)
    into myCount
    from myTable
    where id = myId;
end;
```

Conceptually, I understand what the error means, but I don't know how it applies to my situation. All I've done is moved the hardcoded value to a variable in the `declare` block. Why would that affect the results of the `select` when it's the exact same number?

Version is `Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production`.

Comment: dont see how a count can return more than 1 row

Comment: Can you provide a fully working, minimal, example script (an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) that demonstrates your problem? The example given has no problems, which means you've either simplified your example too much or there's something seriously wrong with your Oracle installation (which is highly unlikely when compared to the first option).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something going on in your system that you haven't reproduced in this question.  If I create a table `myTable` in my local system, your code runs without error

```
SQL> create table myTable( id number );

Table created.

SQL> declare
  2      myCount number;
  3      myId number := 1;
  4  begin
  5      select count(*)
  6      into myCount
  7      from myTable
  8      where id = myId;
  9  end;
 10  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Is it possible that there is some difference between the code you've posted and the code that you're actually running?

Comment: Stupid mistake on my part. I had typos that did not make it into my question. Lesson learned, proof read questions.